# Display & Hide a Navbar submenu

Tags: javascript, navbar, submenu

I'm trying to make a navbar with a submenu for each link. The easiest way to do this that I found is to write some Javascript that when the link is clicked changes the classes of the submenu (from display none to display block). I tried to write the script but it doesn't work at all. I can't find out where the problem is.

```html
const SM_prossimieventi = () => {
  const sottomenu = document.querySelector('.prossimieventi_items');
  const linkpe = document.querySelector('.prossimieventi_a');
  linkpe.addEventListener('click', () => {
    sottomenu.classList.toggle('.pe-active');
  });
};

SM_prossimieventi();
```

```html
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul class="main-nav_items">
                <li class="main-nav_item"> <a href="" class="main-nav_item_a home_a">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav_item"> <a href="" class="main-nav_item_a prossimieventi_a">PROSSIMI EVENTI</a></a>
                    <ul class="prossimieventi_items">
                        <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">GIORNATA ECOLOGICA</a></li>
                        <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">CONCORSO FOTOGRAFICO</a></li>
                        <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">LOTTERIA</a></li>
                        <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">FESTA ASSUNTA</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="main-nav_item"> <a href="" class="main-nav_item_a mappainterattiva_a">MAPPA INTERATTIVA</a>
                    <ul class="mappainterattiva_items">
                        <li class="mappainterattiva_item"><a href="">COSA VISITARE</a></li>
                        <li class="mappainterattiva_item"><a href="">DOVE MANGIARE</a></li>
                        <li class="mappainterattiva_item"><a href="">DOVE DORMIRE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav_item"> <a href="" class="main-nav_item_a attivitàsulterritorio_a">ATTIVITA' SUL
                        TERRITORIO</a> </a>
                    <ul class="attivitàsulterritorio_items">
                        <li class="attivitàsulterritorio_item"><a href="">FERRAGOSTO</a></li>
                        <li class="attivitàsulterritorio_item"><a href="">IL NATALE</a></li>
                        <li class="attivitàsulterritorio_item"><a href="">PROGETTO AIUOLE</a></li>
                        <li class="attivitàsulterritorio_item"><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li class="attivitàsulterritorio_item"><a href="">DONAZIONI</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav_item"><a href="" class="main-nav_item_a chisiamo_a">CHI SIAMO</a></a>
                    <ul class="chisiamo_items">
                        <li class="chisiamo_item"><a href="">LA STORIA</a></li>
                        <li class="chisiamo_item"><a href="">CONTATTACI</a></li>
                        <li class="chisiamo_item"><a href="">BILANCIO</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

```html
.mappainterattiva_items,
.prossimieventi_items,
.attivitàsulterritorio_items,
.chisiamo_items {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem 0rem 0rem 1rem;
  background: #1679a7;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight: 275;
  width: max-content;
  display: none;
}
.main-nav_item {
  position: relative;
}
.mappainterattiva_item a,
.prossimieventi_item a,
.attivitàsulterritorio_item a,
.chisiamo_item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mappainterattiva_item a:hover,
.prossimieventi_item a:hover,
.attivitàsulterritorio_item a:hover,
.chisiamo_item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cccc32;
}

.pe-active{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code have several problems:

1. First problem could be that you defined **SM_prossimieventi** function as const. In case you linked your javascript file at the end of your html it won't work. The reason is that const variables (as well as let) are not hoisted, and you will probably get error that this function is not defined. If you are not familiar with concept of hoisting i suggest reading this article: [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

2. This is how your expandSubmenu function should look something like this:

   ```
    function expandSubmenu(event){
   event.target.querySelector('ul').classList.toggle('pe-active')
   ```

   }
3. Attach **exapndSubmenu** function to all top-level li elements - like this:

   ```
            <li class="main-nav_item" onclick="expandSubmenu(event)"> PROSSIMI EVENTI
            <ul class="prossimieventi_items">
                <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">GIORNATA ECOLOGICA</a></li>
                <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">CONCORSO FOTOGRAFICO</a></li>
                <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">LOTTERIA</a></li>
                <li class="prossimieventi_item"><a href="">FESTA ASSUNTA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   ```
4. Remove  tag from top-level li elements, because you are looking for to expand submenu and to go to certain page upon clicking on them
5. **Remove position:absolute** from css file and avoid to use to, only in exceptional

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that click events bubble. You can set one click event listener on .main-nav_items and then use the Event object to get at the target.

In this way you're only dealing with a single event listener.

Something like this...

```
const SM_prossimieventi = () => {
  let list = document.querySelector('.main-nav_items');
  list.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('pe-active');
  })
}

SM_prossimieventi();
```